# How to select a link(line) from an opened .txt file in r?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a .txt file contains 3 download links.

The lines(links) are separated by "Enter" in the .txt file.

Here is the link to download the file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m3hz5haz0ixre14/download_Links.txt?dl=1

I opened the .txt file in R using this code:

```
download_links <- read.table("C:/Users/Desktop/download_Links.txt", sep = "", header = FALSE)
class(download_links)
>
[1] "data.frame"
```

I want to select the first link(line) inside the file, but R gives me all the file contents:

```
download_links[1]

>                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   V1
1 http://esgf-data2.diasjp.net/thredds/fileServer/esg_dataroot/CMIP6/HighResMIP/MRI/MRI-AGCM3-2-H/highresSST-present/r1i1p1f1/day/pr/gn/v20190711/pr_day_MRI-AGCM3-2-H_highresSST-present_r1i1p1f1_gn_19500101-19591231.nc
2 http://esgf-data2.diasjp.net/thredds/fileServer/esg_dataroot/CMIP6/HighResMIP/MRI/MRI-AGCM3-2-H/highresSST-present/r1i1p1f1/day/pr/gn/v20190711/pr_day_MRI-AGCM3-2-H_highresSST-present_r1i1p1f1_gn_19600101-19691231.nc
3 http://esgf-data2.diasjp.net/thredds/fileServer/esg_dataroot/CMIP6/HighResMIP/MRI/MRI-AGCM3-2-H/highresSST-present/r1i1p1f1/day/pr/gn/v20190711/pr_day_MRI-AGCM3-2-H_highresSST-present_r1i1p1f1_gn_19700101-19791231.nc
```

**Question:**

How can I select only one link(line) from the file each time?

I would be very grateful for your comments/answers.

Comment: `read.table()` returns a data.frame so to index a particular value you need to supply both a row and column position - `download_links[1, 1]`.  If your file is just a list of links it would be better to use `readLines()` which will return a vector instead of a data.frame.

Comment: `download_links[1]` selects the first column of the dataframe. What do you want to do after selecting those links one by one ?

Comment: @H 1, thank you very much. Your comment works well. I will answer the question based on your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the helpful comment from @H 1, I am answering the question to complete this topic:

```
download_links <- readLines("C:/Users/Desktop/download_Links.txt")
class(download_links)

>
[1] "character"

download_links[1]

[1] "http://esgf-data2.diasjp.net/thredds/fileServer/esg_dataroot/CMIP6/HighResMIP/MRI/MRI-AGCM3-2-H/highresSST-present/r1i1p1f1/day/pr/gn/v20190711/pr_day_MRI-AGCM3-2-H_highresSST-present_r1i1p1f1_gn_19500101-19591231.nc"
```